# Elasticsearch mapping with nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

It is my mapping. product_base is nested object also manufacturer is child of product_base and nested object. When i create my doc, if product_base count more than 1 , seems product_base.0, product_base.1 . However i couldnt use filter normally. Is my mapping wrong?

When i use filter for example , returns null because in my elasticserach doc. product_base seems as product_base.0 , product_base.1 ....

```
'path'  => 'product_base.lang',
                    'query' => [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => [
                                ['match' => [
                                    product_base.lang.id_product' => 1]],
                                ['match' => [
                                    'product_base.lang.id_lang' => 2]],
                            ],
                        ],



$params = 'index' => product,
     'body'  => [
        'mappings' => [
           '_source'    => [
              'enabled' => true,
           ],
           'properties' => [
              'id_product'        => ['type' => 'integer'],
              'id_product_base'   => ['type' => 'integer'],
              

              'lang' => [
                 'type'       => 'nested',
                 'properties' => [
                    'id_product'  => ['type' => 'integer'],
                    'id_lang'     => ['type' => 'byte'],
                    'name'        => ['type' => 'text']
                    

                 ],
              ],

              'product_base' => [

                 'type'       => 'nested',
                 'properties' => [
                    'id_product_base'       => ['type' => 'integer'],
                    'id_manufacturer'       => ['type' => 'integer'],
                    'id_product_zone_group' => ['type' => 'text'],
                    'status'                => ['type' => 'byte'],

                    'manufacturer' => [

                       'type'       => 'nested',
                       'properties' => [
                          'id_manufacturer' => ['type' => 'integer'],
                          'name'            => ['type' => 'text'],
                          'status'          => ['type' => 'byte'],

                       ],
                    ],

                   ]

                 ]

              ]

              ]
              ]
              ]
            ];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this  "However i couldnt use filter normally"

Comment: lang is outside of product base and in your query you are using product_base.lang

Comment: are you trying to filter on nested document inside another nested document

Comment: It s for example. Problem is in elasticsearch 
prduct_base{
0:{}
1:{}
Is my mapping correct? nested in nested ?
}

Comment: mapping is correct. To access nested field you have to use nested query, If there is nested field inside another nested the query should be same to nested query inside another nested query. Nested type treats an array as array of separate documents